# I want to draw the recursion tree for T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n and derive a guess to upper bound

Tags: recursion, tree, recurrence

I derived as T(n) = O(n). But I can't prove it from substitution method.Please prove the answer too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to prove this for you because I think this is probably a homework problem and I have ethical concerns about doing your homework for you. However, I would be happy to give you a sense for why you're having trouble proving that T(n) = 3T(n / 2) + n.

Let's think about the recursion tree. At the top level, we have one node of size n that does n work. Below it, we have three nodes of size n / 2, each of which does n / 2 work. Summing across that row, we see that the work done is 3n / 2. Each of those three nodes generates three new nodes of size n / 4. That means that in the next layer there are nine nodes each doing n / 4 work, so the total work done on that layer is 9n / 4.

If you follow the pattern here, you'll notice that the work done in the kth layer is (3/2)<sup>k</sup>n. This grows as k increases, so the work done actually isn't going to be O(n).

Play around with this observation and with the iteration method. How many layers are there going to be? Based on that, what is the runtime going to be?